# problem running php script from command line and connecting to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a basic php script that runs perfect in a browser.  I want to run this same php script at the shell command line (Freebsd 8.0), but I'm having troubles when the script tries to connect to the database using "mysql_query"....the rest of the script runs fine, but the connection to the database just doesn't happen.

I verified that the php.ini in phpinfo() is what I am using, but still nothing.

Here's the command:

```
php -c /usr/local/etc/php.ini /data/phpscript.php
```

The ouptput should be an array of data, which i verified the SQL with in phpmyadmin and results are there, instead it returns nothing and I don't get any error messages in the log files.

Any ideas whats going on here?  I've always used the browser to run my php stuff, but this time I need to put it into a crontab and run it from the server directly on a schedule.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you're not setting any variables based on information that isn't available when running in CLI mode? (e.g.: You're not basing your DB settings on the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] or on an environmental variable that's set via SetEnv or similar?)

Comment: yeah, it's not pulling from an environment var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echo the error code and error string the mysqli function can give you after each run.
 Also check that your php.ini does not shut down your error messages (so you do not see anything as there is no Apache error log in CLI).
This two steps should give you the answer.

Comment: thanks, I dug into the database class and echoed out the results of the query and it is looking for a table that only exists in the dev environment, but when running at command line it is defaulting to the production box database location.  thanks for the tip, I'll try to figure out how to get it to connect to the dev database.

Answer (score 1):

## setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1

Comment: Big plus. Thanks a lot for this answer. We tried everything and nothing worked before this.